# Не видит файл в консоли

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Как запустить исполняемый файл в шелле ./aapt? Полный абсурд. Пробывал выдавать файлу chmod +x, запускать через шебанг #!/bin/sh, также запускал от другого пользователя. Не работает

Не работает. Что не так?
[image: как-то так]

Вот вывод прав
[image: права]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Команда `file aapt` вам всё расскажет. Если не всё, то ещё есть `ldd aapt`.

Comment: @0andriy Вот вывод: root@173188:/# file ./aapt
./aapt: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-, for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped
root@173188:/# ldd aapt
 not a dynamic executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил, не знаю, что это такое, но помогло в итоге:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

Comment: Вам `file aapt` всё показал: у вас на 64-битной системе запускается 32-битный бинарник. Для этого нужна поддержка multilib. И по счастливой случайности вы вытянули пакет, который притащил нужную зависимость. Однако, этот метод -- хак, правильно надо было сделать, установив пакет `libc:i386`.